# $|\int _0^1 f(x)dx|\le \frac{1}{4} \max_{0\le x\le 1} |f'(x)|$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

let $f(x)\in C^1[0,1], f(0)=f(1)=0$ then $|\int _0^1 f(x)dx|\le \frac{1}{4} \max_{0\le x\le 1} |f'(x)|$

How prove this

I started with $f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ with using definition of derivative but im not getting any idea so far

Comment: Use the fundamental theorem of calculus to express $f(x)$ as an integral of $f'$ from $0$ to $x$ if $x\le 1/2$ and from $x$ to $1$ if $x\ge 1/2$ and then majorize with $\max |f'|$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use integration by parts to show $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx=\int_0^1\left(\frac12-x\right)f'(x)\,dx$. Hence $$\left|\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx\right|\leqslant\max_{0\leqslant x\leqslant 1}|f'(x)|\int_0^1\left|\frac12-x\right|\,dx,$$ and the remaining integral is easily evaluated (and equals $1/4$).